# Specify `max` Without `size` when Creating MongoDB Capped Collection

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo, capped-collections

When trying to create a MongoDB capped collection with only a limit for the max number of documents and not a size limit (not sure how large will all the documents be), `pymongo` is giving the error

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: specify size:<n> when capped is true
```

after running

```
db.create_collection('helloworld', capped=True, max=86400)
```

Is it possible to just define the `max` parameter?

Otherwise, is there any danger in putting a very large number for `size`?

Answer (score 1):

[As the docs say](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections/):

> The size argument is always required, even when you specify max number of documents. MongoDB will remove older documents if a collection reaches the maximum size limit before it reaches the maximum document count.

MongoDB pre-allocates data files of the requested maximum size, so set that size parameter to something reasonable.